# Trying to change properties of another element within .click() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the text color of an element when I click a button using jQuery. This code is not working, please help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#colorChange").style.color = "blue";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="colorChange">I should(?) change color when you click mr. button</p>
<button>clickme</button>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/css  Use the correct functions.  jQuery does not directly expose attributes/properties of dom elements.

Comment: Alternatively you could get the raw dom element with `$("#colorChange")[0]` and your property access would work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `$("#colorChange").css("color", "blue")` instead of `$("#colorChange").style.color = "blue"`.

For more info, visit: https://api.jquery.com/css

Answer (score 1):

hope this help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("#colorChange").css("color","blue"); 
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="colorChange">I should(?) change color when you click mr. button</p>
<button>clickme</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explain what the issue is and how you fixed it.  Don't just post code.

Comment: @AboAlimk thank you, as you can tell im new to jQuery and didnt realize you cant use plain javascript methods with jQuery selectors

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
$("#colorChange").style.color = "blue";
```

It should look like this:

```
$("#colorChange")[0].style.color = "blue";
```

This is because the object returned from `$("#colorChange")` is a [jQuery Object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/). The style property you wish to change is a member of a [DOM Element](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp), which can be retrieved from the jQuery Object with an array index or the `get()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
$("button").click(function(){
     $("#colorChange").css("color","blue"); 
});
```

this one also works fine,

```
$("button").click(function(){
     $("#colorChange")[0].style.color= 'blue'; 
});
```